# Set Open DNS in Android 5.0.1

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, dns

Just updated my Oneplus One to Android 5.0.1, and I can't change the DNS when I select the "Static IP" option in Wi-Fi settings. Basically I can put the values in, there is just no way to press OK and accept the changes.

It was possible in Android 4.4.2. Has anyone bumped into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is one silly issue in Lollipop update (CM12) for OnePlus. I'm assuming you're running Cyanogen OS 12, and I found (on Reddit) and tested this solution some time ago.

Unlike Kitkat, you can't change only the DNS in Wifi settings as "Save"/"OK" is always greyed out if you do, i.e. you need to provide every single detail which includes:

- IP address
- Gateway
- Network prefix length
- DNS 1
- DNS 2

As soon as you fill the first four entries, the option will appear to save the settings.

A brief description of each field is given [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205775/218526).