# where are DNS settings under 4.4.2?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, networking, reverse-tether, dns

I cannot find where to configure [DNS settings](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) for this device:

```
Model number:        astar
Processor type:      QuadCore-A33
Android version:     4.4.2
Firmware version:    v2.0
Kernel version:      3.4.39
                     mmy@ubuntu #1
                     Fri Sep 25 14:17:42 CST 2015
Build number:        astar-rt18703-eng 4.4.2 KVT49L 20150925 test-keys
```

Based on a [previous](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/109844/48164) question, it seems possible -- I've looked all through settings on wi-fi, ethernet, etc.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No.  Do I need to root it?  Or install some variant?

Comment: I don't know if there are other variants, but if you're rooted, there are many ways to change DNS.. I'm not telling you to root, I just asked..

Comment: did the answer in your linked question answer it? Or did you use and app or maybe  go to root? i am having a dsn issue [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157347/changing-dns-settings-on-android-not-working)